# Centering ticks on row of a heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, row, heatmap

I have attempted to move my yticks on the heat map below to the centre of the row it corresponds to.

This has worked, except for the fact I now get the white space at the bottom of the graph. Is there a way to achieve the ticks in the middle without the white space?

**Original image & code**:

[image]

```
heatmap = plt.pcolor(df2.T, cmap=cmap,  vmax=1, vmin=0)
plt.yticks(range(len(df2.columns )+1), o, size=15)
```

**New Image & Code**

[image]

```
heatmap = plt.pcolor(df2.T, cmap=cmap,  vmax=1, vmin=0)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0.5, len(df2.columns)+1,1), df2.columns, size=15)
```

**Attempts**

I have tried using

`plt.yticks(np.arange(0.5, len(df2.columns)+0.5,1), o, size=15`

*Note the change from +1 to +0.5* This however, halves my bottom row. See below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ylim` to set the yaxis range:

```
plt.ylim(0, df2.shape[1])
```

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning `ax.axis('tight')`, in this case.